# Apache Spark-Java version 3.3 importing problems

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Beginner in implementing Apache Spark in my Java project. I'm using Spark-3.3, and the jars are downloaded from the maven repository. A simple snippet as the following throws an error, I'm very confusing:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in_path = "./test.csv";
        String out_path = "./out.csv";
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("CSV to Dataset")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load(in_path);

        //write
        Dataset<Row> outputDf = df
                .filter("confidence_level = 'high'")
                .repartition(1);
        outputDf
                .write()
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", true)
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .save(out_path);
    }
}
```

One can make a .csv file to reproduce this error:

```
,step,value
0,0,0.48335474743993967
1,1,0.1158508331018181
2,2,0.9587111373188968
3,3,0.8701416114549719
4,4,0.1568403204008163
5,5,0.12215751676273201
6,6,0.5040615339539852
7,7,0.5291894043380058
8,8,0.40721487378992893
9,9,0.9284453533942072
10,10,0.8224097122571449
11,11,0.31928057533043286
12,12,0.9255140336657344
```

The error is this:

> java: cannot access scala.collection.immutable.Seq   class file for
> scala.collection.immutable.Seq not found

Many thanks

---

Update1:
After including all these jars:

```
spark-sql_2.13-3.3.0.jar
spark-network-common_2.13-3.3.0.jar
spark-mllib_2.13-3.3.0.jar
spark-core_2.13-3.3.0.jar
spark-catalyst_2.13-3.3.0.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.36.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
scala-library-2.13.8.jar
log4j-core-2.18.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.3.4.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.3.4.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.3.4.jar
hadoop-common-3.3.4.jar
hadoop-client-3.3.4.jar
guava-31.1-jre.jar
commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
```

It still throws:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/hadoop/thirdparty/com/google/common/collect/Maps

A nightmare, now I cannot find which jar is related to.

Comment: How are you running the code? What does your pom.xml looks like?

Comment: @GaëlJ I include jars manually

Comment: You should use a dependency management tool like Maven, otherwise it will be a pain to maintain and find all the JARs you need.

Comment: I'm restricted to only use jars in this project

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly different version of `spark`, but I think steps below won't be any different.

Suppose I have `spark-3.1.2` installed here: `/home/qq/.sdkman/candidates/spark/3.1.2/`

Suppose also I have `Main.java` like yours.

I compiled and run it without errors like this:

```
javac -cp .:/home/qq/.sdkman/candidates/spark/3.1.2/jars/* Main.java
java -cp .:/home/qq/.sdkman/candidates/spark/3.1.2/jars/* Main
```

Answer (score 1):

I *strongly* suggest to use a depedency management tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). You will sooner or later have to update your Spark version (if only for bugfixes or fixed security flaws). Spark 3.3.0 needs at least 139 different jars (plus optional packages like [MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/mllib/) or [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/graphx/)). Managing the correct versions of 139+ different jars is no fun!

If you cannot use Maven directly in your project, you can at least use this tool to create the list of jars that you have to include:

First create a minimal `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
  <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>simplesparkapp</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then use Maven's [dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) to either

- create a [list](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html) of all required jars: `mvn dependency:list` (result is [here](https://gist.github.com/werner288/6a1d20dd76ab2ccb0e4064953b816740)) or
- let Maven [copy all required jars](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) into a folder on your machine: `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=out`

This way you can at least automate parts of your build and deployment road.